# Jquery Slideshow No Fade

Tags: jquery, slideshow

http://www.beulahprint.ie

I'm trying to build a client testimonials slideshow. I want about 10 divs, each div will have an image and some text in it, and jQuery cycles through the divs, pausing for a few seconds on each div and repeats the cycle when finished. One div is showing at a time, with no fade.

Alternatively, I could have just one div, with alternating content if this is possible?

I have images fading on my site currently, but I can't find any help on div slideshows with no fades.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a plug in described [here](http://stephenwalther.com/blog/archive/2010/10/02/jquery-cycle-plugin-on-the-microsoft-ajax-cdn.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a+StephenWalther+%28Stephen+Walther+on+ASP.NET+MVC%29) that lets you cycle through images using any effect you like.

Comment: In the client testimonials section of my site, you can see i have already set it up to cycle through images. The thing is, I want to cycle through divs, not images. Is this possible?

Comment: The plugin provides a method called cycle which is invoked on a container element. Each child element of the container becomes a "slide"  from here:http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/ , would seem to suggest you can use a div as the container objects.

Comment: Just tested this and it works. let me know if you get any problems

Comment: That's beautiful man, sorry for the slow reply, still getting used to this coding business! It looks well now, but the effect doesn't look quite smooth enough, is there some way around this? Is it the easing effect? If so, how can I implement this? Thanks for your help so far man, really appreciate it!

Comment: @Colm, I haven't really played enough with JQuery animations, here might be a good place to start http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/

Comment: sorry I clicked that by accident.

Answer (score 0):

I usually use 1 div that represents the slideshow, together with a hidden unnumbered list with the items that need to be displayed.

```
<div id="slideshow">
   <div id="image"></div>
</div>
<ul id="images" style="display:none;">
   <li>image1.jpg</li>
   <li>image2.jpg</li>
</ul>
```

You can run trough the list with jquery next() function (http://api.jquery.com/next). Get the html value of the current list item and set the background of the div#image to that value.

Comment: But that will just display a list of images right? Can I set it up to run through a list of divs? With each div containing an image and text?

Comment: No it will not show the list because of the display:none; It just uses the list to help cycling through the images.

Comment: No I mean, I want to cycle through a list of divs, not a list of images. Is this possible?